# Failed assertion: line 4191 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two list view builder as the below image retrieving from fire store:

[image]

Error while trying to get specific list of items and this is the below error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 4

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      AppCubit.changeCategoryModelState (package:ipet/shared/cubit/cubit.dart:116:35)
#2      CategoriesScreen.buildPetsCategoryItem.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:ipet/modules/categories/categories_screen.dart:97:43)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#0916b
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(272.1, 219.8)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(51.1, 42.8)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

So I want to when click on item from `buildPetsCategoryItem()` just Change the `buildCategoriesListView()`

So what is the best way to do this...

This is the below code:

```
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: cubit.scrollController,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: CustomText(
                  text: "Categories",
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              // buildCategoryItem(context),
              buildPetsCategoryItem(context),
              buildCategoriesListView(cubit)
            ],
          ),
        );
```

to be more clear I have this below categoriesBuilder:

```
 Widget buildPetsCategoryItem(context) {
    return Container(
      height: 120,
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: AppCubit.get(context).petsCategories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    AppCubit.get(context).changePetsCategoryBorder(index);
                    AppCubit.get(context).changeCategoryModelState(index);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: customShadow,
                      border:
                          AppCubit.get(context).selectedPetsCategory == index
                              ? Border.all(
                                  color: secondaryGreen,
                                  width: 2,
                                )
                              : null,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                      AppCubit.get(context).petsCategories[index].image,
                      scale: 1.8,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Text(
                  AppCubit.get(context).petsCategories[index].name,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

and this is the CategoriesListView:

```
  ListView buildCategoriesListView(AppCubit cubit) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: cubit.currentCategoryPets.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            navigateTo(
              context,
              DetailsScreen(
                pets: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index],
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            child: PetCard(
              petId: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].id,
              petName: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].name,
              age: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].age,
              breed: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].petType,
              gender: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].gender,
              distance: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].distance,
              imagePath: cubit.currentCategoryPets[index].image,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

as I have both methods which get the `PetsModel` data for each category one gets all the pets, and the other get the Cats one:

```
  List<PetsModel> pets = [];
  List<PetsModel> cats = [];
  void getPetsData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pets').get().then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        pets.add(PetsModel.fromJson(element.data()));
      });
      emit(AppGetPetsSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(AppGetPetsErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }

  void getCatsData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pets').where('type', isEqualTo: 'cat').get().then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        cats.add(PetsModel.fromJson(element.data()));
      });
      emit(AppGetPetsSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(AppGetPetsErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }
```

I tried to create a method that changes the `Category Model State` as the below one:

```
  PetsModel petModel;
  List<PetsModel> currentCategoryModel = [];

  void changeCategoryModelState(int position) {
    petModel = currentCategoryPets[position];
    if (position == 4) getPetsData();
    if (position == 5) getCatsData();
    emit(AppChangeCategoryModelState());
  }
```

this is the main class which contains the BlocProvider:

```
return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()
        ..getUserData()
        ..getCategoriesData()
        ..getPetsData()
        ..getCatsData()
        ..handleScroll(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(...),);
```

for more infos this is the pet card widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // final randomColor = colors[_random.nextInt(colors.length)];
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      height: 240,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            // height: 200,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 70,
              bottom: 20,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: size.width * 0.48,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            CustomText(
                              text: petName,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              maxLine: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              gender == 'female'
                                  ? FontAwesomeIcons.venus
                                  : FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                              size: 18,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text(
                          breed,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: fadedBlack,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomText(
                          text: age + ' years',
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: fadedBlack,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.location_pin,
                              size: 16,
                              color: primaryGreen,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            CustomText(
                              text: 'Distance: ' + distance + ' Km',
                              fontSize: 12,
                              color: fadedBlack,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: customShadow,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: size.width * 0.48,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    boxShadow: customShadow,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                ),
                Align(
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: petId,
                    child: Image.network(
                      imagePath,
                      loadingBuilder: loadingNetworkImage,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

the below method is related for `selectedPetsCategories()`:

```
  int selectedPetsCategory = 0;

  void changePetsCategoryBorder(int index) {
    selectedPetsCategory = index;
    emit(AppChangePetsCategoryBorderState());
  }
```

How can I solve this error?

## Edited

So for the previous error because I have to add the `changeCategoryModelState()` method in init while starting the app in the blocProvider so I have make the `int position` argument as an optional and tried to add the method `addAll` as the below code:

```
  void changeCategoryModelState({int position}) {
    petModel = currentCategoryPets[position];
    if (position == 4) getPetsData();
    if (position == 5) getCatsData();
    currentCategoryPets.addAll(pets);
    emit(AppChangeCategoryModelState());
  }
```

and called it in the main like the below code:

```
return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()
        ..getUserData()
        ..getCategoriesData()
        ..getPetsData()
        ..getCatsData()
        ..changeCategoryModelState()
        ..handleScroll(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(...),);
```

I found the below error:

```
E/flutter ( 4506): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2651 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
E/flutter ( 4506): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
The following assertion was thrown attaching to the render tree:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4191 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Element.rebuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4191:14)
#3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4194:6)
#4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4474:5)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4469:5)
#6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
```

Comment: Isn't the `currentCategoryPets` list empty on the first `changeCategoryModelState()` call?

Comment: @mkobuolys nope I didn't trying to call it yet till I create the other methods, I just want to see the result as the other categories in the firestore is emty also, it is supposed the the All Category it's position 4 and the cat one position 5

Comment: And what's happening inside `AppCubit.get(context).changePetsCategoryBorder(index);` or `AppCubit.get(context).changeCategoryModelState(index);`?

Comment: @mkobuolys the first method change the border radius when select item and the other method should gives me the Category model which I select

Comment: So maybe the second method calls an item with an index that is out of range?

Comment: @mkobuolys I have 7 categories Item I am calling the fifth and the sixth only because the others are still empty

Comment: But inside `buildPetsCategoryItem()` you are going through all the categories (`itemCount: AppCubit.get(context).petsCategories.length`) and building them even though these categories are empty?

Comment: @mkobuolys may be I should call the changeCategoryModelState() in the init? I didn't call it

Comment: I don't know, it's hard to say without seeing the whole code and how it works, but sure, you can try.

Comment: @mkobuolys let me try add the main code, between yes they are empty in the firestore for the other categories but I have one item in type cat and 5 items in the other type but let me update the main class now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232963/discussion-between-mahmoud-harooney-and-mkobuolys).

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer then just remove the arguments and update the`changeCategoryModelState` method to:

```
  void changeCategoryModelState() {
    if (selectedPetsCategory == 5) {
      currentCategoryPets.clear();
      currentCategoryPets.addAll(cats);
      print(selectedPetsCategory.toString());
    }
    else if (selectedPetsCategory == 4) {
      currentCategoryPets.clear();
      currentCategoryPets.addAll(pets);
      print(selectedPetsCategory.toString());
    }
    emit(AppChangeCategoryModelState());
  }
```